# Altbeacon Transmitter onStartSuccess calls only once is that the right behavior?

Tags: android, altbeacon

I am new the Andriod and Beacons, I tried to implement Transmitter (publisher using Samsung S7 android phone as a Beacon) and Receiver (listener) using andriod another phonE of Samsung s7. For that, I am trying to use Altbeacon library 2-10.

First my question is will it be possible to transmit without a real beacon. I don't want to simulate. I want to use one mobile as a beacon and another mobile as a receiver.

If so, I tried implementing the code for Transmitter, I can see only once AdvertiseCallback calling and enter into onStartSuccess ONLY Once in the lifetime of the application. Is that the right behaviour? Or Do I need to write and schedule to keep call the callback?

Please advice me. [The snippet of the code below]

```
 callback =  new AdvertiseCallback() {
         @Override
         public void onStartSuccess(AdvertiseSettings settingsInEffect) {
             super.onStartSuccess(settingsInEffect);
             Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Advertisement start succeeded .");
         }

         @Override
         public void onStartFailure(int errorCode) {
             super.onStartFailure(errorCode);
             Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Advertisement Failed ERROR "+Integer.toString(errorCode));
         }
     };

    beaconTransmitter.startAdvertising(beacon, callback);
```

Comment: try adding `AdvertiseSettings.Builder`, ref: [AltBeacon transmitter](https://github.com/AltBeacon/altbeacon-transmitter-android)

Answer (score 0):

The BeaconTransmitter will send out a real BluetoothLE advertisement on compatible devices that is indistinguishable from the output of a dedicated a hardware transmitter.  It creates a real beacon.

The callback should be issued once for each callback instance where you change the transmitter state.  In other words, if you call start twice with the same callback, you may not get a second callback.  You would need to show where in context you make the call to `startAdvertisement`.  If you want to guarantee a callback, try stopping transmission before calling to start a second time.

Regardless, the best way to test if it is working is to use a second device to scan for the advertisement and verify a beacon us detected.  See here for more info: http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/beacon-transmitter.html

Comment: I have gone throw the altbeacon site and its ref. sample. After transmitting.  I also implemented Consumer application with all valid permissions mentioned in the site. Even after my consumer is not able to see any even occurring on ‘addMonitorNotifier’ in that didEnterRegion and didExitRegion . I only can see calling happing in  didRangeBeaconsInRegion(...) entry but I always see beacons collection is NULL.  My consumer application not able recognise any of my transmitter application. Even I have installed beacon simulator app transmitting still I can see beacon collection is null.

Comment: I only can see call invoking below method with always beacon collection is NULL. @Override public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {               Log.d(TAG,"onBeaconServiceConnect:"+region.getUniqueId()+"ID1"+region.getId1().toString());if (beacons != null && beacons.size() > 0) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "The first beacon I see is "+beacons.iterator().next().getDistance()+" meters away.");
                }
               }

Comment: Try installing this app on two Android devices:  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.radiusnetworks.locate&hl=en  It uses the same library to transmit and receive.  First make sure you can use the Locate app to transmit, and to see the same Locate app transmission with a copy of the Locate app on a different phone.   Then try seeing if the Locate app will see your custom app's transmission.  Then see if you can detect the Locate app's transmission in your custom app.  Depending on what doesn't work, you'll know where the problem is.

Comment: Thaks for your kind advice and I simulated based on the tool you recommended. I able to fix the issue 1. Permissions need to be enabled. 2. I missed to implements from BootstrapNotifier.